# How to get Block Style Progressbars in Aero / .NET 4

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, coding-style, progress-bar

I have three ProgressBars of the three styles.  Blocks and Continuous are now rendering the same, whereas I remember Blocks used to render as Blocks.

http://www.kconnolly.net/pics/pb.jpg

is this unique to .NET 4, Aero Glass, or Windows 7?  How can I tell my app to use the classic Blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
public class ContinuousProgressBar : ProgressBar 
{ 
    public ContinuousProgressBar() 
    { 
        this.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous; 
    }
    protected override void CreateHandle()
    {
        base.CreateHandle();
        try
        {
            SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "", "");
        }
        catch 
        { 
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]  
    private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hwnd, string appname, string idlist);
}
```